# String passed to Class appear null

Tags: scala

Here is my short Code :

```
class InnoString(abc: String)extends App{

  val message=abc

  override def toString(): String ={
    return message
  }



  def concat(sub : String): String={
      return  s"$sub$message"
    }
}



object checkInno extends App{
  val x = new InnoString("harshil")
  println(x)
  println(x.concat("there "))
}
```

The result now is  :

> ```
> here
> null
> there null
> ```

Expected output is :

> ```
> here
> harshil
> there harshil
> ```

Comment: Why does the class extends App? Why should it print "here"?

Comment: println ("here") was a check forgot to remove. And `extends App` was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `App` changes how variables are initialized. Remove the `extends App` and it will behave as you expect.